# Homebrew extend CurlDownloadStrategy with curl option

Tags: ruby, gitlab, homebrew

can does anyone know how to extend the `CurlDownloadStrategy` from homebrew with a header? I already did research here and in the github issues but could not find any simple and working answer. Basically it's for gitlab and I need to set a header.

I found a [snippet](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/pouring-bottle-from-private-tap-fails/6062/4) here, fixed a typo but when I run `brew install mytab/mytool --debug`
it does not use the given `--header` option but the standard options as described in the official [code](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/fdbf93536464062fc3f3053492f88fc5bc1f7b38/Library/Homebrew/download_strategy.rb#L277)

Here's what I have:

```rb
require "download_strategy"

class PrivateRepositoryDownloadStrategy < CurlDownloadStrategy
  def initialize(url, name, version, **meta)
    super
    set_gitlab_token
  end

  private

  def _fetch(url:, resolved_url:)
    args = ["--header", "Private-Token: #{@gitlab_token}"]
    curl_download(@url, *args, to: temporary_path)
  end

  def set_gitlab_token
    @gitlab_token = ENV["HOMEBREW_GITLAB_ACCESS_TKN"]
    unless @gitlab_token
      raise CurlDownloadStrategyError, "Environment variable HOMEBREW_GITLAB_ACCESS_TKN is required."
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the issue. Basically I needed to be able to download the artifact from the gitlab uploads of a repository. The issue is there that we need to pass a custom header to `curl` and the `CurlDownloadStrategy` has already the option to pass in custom header and cookies (`-b`) according to this [snippet](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/fdbf93536464062fc3f3053492f88fc5bc1f7b38/Library/Homebrew/download_strategy.rb#L420). I learned some ruby on the way and the `PrivateRepositoryDownloadStrategy` is not needed any more  :)

So my final formula looks like this:

```rb
# This file was generated by GoReleaser. DO NOT EDIT.
class MyTool < Formula
  desc "mytool desc"
  homepage "https://gitab.mycompany/group/tool"
  version "0.0.1"
  bottle :unneeded

  if OS.mac?
    url "https://gitab.mycompany/group/tool/uploads/d046fcf878e88dd02312f15da23c5e00/mytool_Darwin_x86_64.tar.gz", :cookies => [["_gitlab_session", "#{ENV['HOMEBREW_GITLAB_SESSION_ACCESS_TOKEN']}"]]
    sha256 "8f3957fdf78fde15d900229b29cae81c490eb585ff220acd7f0d71b4244f8d02"
  elsif OS.linux?
    if Hardware::CPU.intel?
      url "https://gitab.mycompany/group/tool/uploads/6082ce9fead78d6029c9ac091d4dacda/mytool_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz", :cookies => [["_gitlab_session", "#{ENV['HOMEBREW_GITLAB_SESSION_ACCESS_TOKEN']}"]]
      sha256 "d9713c89f565f2981ef7bc7a63d87ab7f7d84a00c7b3ffbc585ff959097f3d64"
    end
  end

  def install
    bin.install "mytool"
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}/mytool --help"
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**:
I also managed to fix the custom formula

```rb
require "download_strategy"

class PrivateRepositoryDownloadStrategy < CurlDownloadStrategy
  def initialize(url, name, version, **meta)
    super
    set_gitlab_session_token
  end

  private

  def _curl_args
    args = ["-b", "_gitlab_session=#{@gitlab_session_token}"]
    args
  end

  def set_gitlab_session_token
    @gitlab_session_token = ENV["HOMEBREW_GITLAB_SESSION_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
    unless @gitlab_session_token
      raise CurlDownloadStrategyError, "Environment variable HOMEBREW_GITLAB_SESSION_ACCESS_TOKEN is required."
    end
  end
end
```

and an adapted Formula

```rb
require_relative "./PrivateRepositoryDownloadStrategy"
class MyTool < Formula
  desc "mytool desc"
  homepage "https://gitab.mycompany/group/tool"
  version "0.0.1"
  bottle :unneeded

  if OS.mac?
    url "https://gitab.mycompany/group/tool/uploads/d046fcf878e88dd02312f15da23c5e00/mytool_Darwin_x86_64.tar.gz", :using => PrivateRepositoryDownloadStrategy
    sha256 "8f3957fdf78fde15d900229b29cae81c490eb585ff220acd7f0d71b4244f8d02"
  elsif OS.linux?
    if Hardware::CPU.intel?
      url "https://gitab.mycompany/group/tool/uploads/6082ce9fead78d6029c9ac091d4dacda/mytool_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz", :using => PrivateRepositoryDownloadStrategy
      sha256 "d9713c89f565f2981ef7bc7a63d87ab7f7d84a00c7b3ffbc585ff959097f3d64"
    end
  end

  def install
    bin.install "mytool"
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}/mytool --help"
  end
end
```